# Java Syntactic Sugar

Tags: java, syntactic-sugar

I ran into this block of code today, and I don't know how it works. I know how to make anonymous classes, but I'm used to seeing a method signature and not just a pair of braces. Is the code between those braces put into a static block? Does it go into the constructor? Or is it something else altogether?

```
conext.checking(new Expectations() {
    { // <- what does this pair of braces do?
        oneOf(alarm).getAttackAlarm(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an instance initializer that calls the code within the context of the created object.

This is equivalent to

```
Expectations exp = new Expectations();
exp.oneOf(alarm).getAttackAlarm(null);
conext.checking(exp)
```

Whoever wrote it might have thought he was being more efficient by not declaring a variable (not true) or that it was cleaner code (I disagree).

The primary place that these initializers are useful like this is when instantiating maps, ie:

```
Map map = new HashMap() {{
  put("key1", "value1");   
  put("key2", "value2"); 
}};
```

which I think actually is slightly more readable.

Comment: It's called an "instance initializer", not a "static initializer" (the latter wouldn't have `this` for obvious reasons). Also see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6

Comment: It is not a static initializer, just an (instance) initializer.  That block will be run *everytime* that code is run, not just the first time as would happen with a static initializer.

Comment: That `Expectations` is actually pattern from jMock mocking library. Neat idea, but it's actually really confusing in the long run.

Comment: This specific example is, I believe, the recommended (by their documentation) way to do this in jMock 2. It does a lot to try to make test code written with it read fairly naturally.

Comment: Readable, yes.  But I find it absolutely abhorrent to do that (outside of test/scripting code anyway).  It creates an extra class (and class file) for every map you create that way, taking up more permgen space, etc.

Comment: Your "equivalent" example isn't. In the OPs code, the initialiser block (and, therefore, the `oneOf()` call) runs before any constructors. In your example, the (no-args) constructor runs before the `oneOf()` call.

Comment: dty: Not true. I just made a test class to verify that. The constructor gets run before the initializer. Static initializers run before the constructor, but this isn't a static initializer.

Comment: @ReverendGonzo So anonymous classes/inner classes don't have any advantage on creating a new named instance of the Object, except for less coding?

Answer (score 4):

It is an initializer block, but not necessarily a **static** initializer block.  It is effectively a constructor for an anonymous inner class.  You will typically see this "double-brace initialization" pattern to conveniently create and populate collections:

```
private final Collection<Integer> FIXED_COLLECTION = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new HashSet<Integer>() 
{ // first set of braces declares anonymous inner class
    { add(1); add(2); add(3); } // second set is initializer block
});
```

Comment: I have to say, in 15 years of Java programming, I've never come across an initialiser used like that before.

Answer (score 3):

It's an instance initialiser (not a static initialiser).

Consider the definition of a class

```
public class Foo {
    private int i = getDefaultValue();

    private static int getDefaultValue() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The call to `getDefaultValue()` that initalises `i` is essentially a code block that runs each time an instance of Foo is constructed.  The notation extends that function to allow more complex initialisation.  E.g.

```
public class Foo {
    private int i;

    {
        int z = 4 + 5;
        i = z + getDefaultValue();
    }

    private static int getDefaultValue() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The manner with which it is used in JMock is a trick to give expectations the look of a closure construct.

Comment: +1 for noting usage outside of anonymous classes. I also like the reference to closures! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening ? The *outer* braces create a new anonymous class derived from Exception. The *inner* braces define an initialiser and sets the `oneOf()` etc.

Why do this ? It's a one-liner trick for constructing and initialising an instance of a class. e. you sometimes see something like this:

```
new HashSet<String>(){{ add("one"); add("two"); }}
```

to initialise the contents of a collection.

Downsides ? Because you're creating an anonymous class within the containing class, that anonymous class contains a this reference to the outer class implicitly. Not normally a problem, but it can cause issues if (say) you want to serialise a class that you've constructed like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an initializer block. I can't tell what it does without looking at the rest of the code.

The trick is to imagine "new Expectation()" replaced with "class Something extends Expectation".

Answer (score 0):

Anynoymous inner classes don't have a constructor, so you can define a an instance initilizer like this i.e. the inner set of braces are the instance initializers.

```
new Expectations() { 
    { 
        oneOf(alarm).getAttackAlarm(null); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This syntax is not limited to anonymous classes. Although its use is unnecessary and confusing in a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

The primary motivation behind this, I believe, is to create a new name space, in which names defined in `Expection` can be referenced more easily.

For example, suppose `java.lang.Math` is not final,

```
new Math()
{{
    double x = sin(23.65);
    double y = log(x);
    ...
}};
```

It's almost as if we have something like

```
with names from Math
{
    double x = sin(23.65);
    double y = log(x);
    ...
}
```